# Imprimir o ID da Thread

Tags: java, thread

tenho o seguinte codigo e não consigo imprimir o ID da Thread,só o tamanho. Como faço para imprimir o ID do array de threads?

```
public class MultiplicacaoMatrizesThread {
// Matriz A
public static int a[][] = { { 5, 4 }, { 3, 3 }, { 2, 4 } };
// Matriz B
public static int b[][] = { { 3, 2 }, { 8, 2 }, { 5, 8 } };

// Numero de threads
public static final int NUMERO_DE_THREAD = (a.length * b[0].length);
// Matriz resultante
public static int r[][] = new int[3][3];

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int indice_thread = 0;
    Thread[] thread = new Thread[NUMERO_DE_THREAD];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            thread[indice_thread] = new Thread(new GeraMatrizThread(linha,
                    coluna, a, b, r));
            thread[indice_thread].start(); 
            thread[indice_thread].join();
            ++indice_thread;
        }
    }
    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            System.out.print("[" + r[linha][coluna] + "] ");

            System.out.println(thread.length);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi bem, para que você possa imprimir o ID do array de Thread, tente o seguinte :

```
    int indice_thread = 0;
    Thread[] thread = new Thread[NUMERO_DE_THREAD];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            thread[indice_thread] = new Thread();
            thread[indice_thread].start(); 
            thread[indice_thread].join();
            /** Imprime o Id da Thread que acabou de criar! **/
            System.out.println("ID: "+thread[indice_thread].getId());
            ++indice_thread;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando acessar o ID no array e não nos elementos. Para acessar os IDs individualmente você precisa percorrer o array de threads no segundo loop como fez no primeiro.

Exemplo:

```
indice_thread = 0;
for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
        System.out.print("[" + r[linha][coluna] + "] ");
        System.out.println(thread[indice_thread].getId());
        ++indice_thread;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Entretanto, você poderia fazer o vetor de threads multidimensional como os demais e simplificar o código assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[][] thread = new Thread[a.length][b[0].length];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new GeraMatrizThread(linha, coluna, a, b, r));
            t.start();
            t.join();
            thread[linha][coluna] = t;
        }
    }

    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            System.out.print("[" + r[linha][coluna] + "] ");
            System.out.println(thread[linha][coluna].getId());
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Por fim, o uso do `Thread#join` está incorreto. Do jeito que está, o primeiro loop vai esperar a finalização de cada *thread* antes de prosseguir. O correto é criar todas as threads e chamar o join antes de coletar os resultados, como abaixo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[][] thread = new Thread[a.length][b[0].length];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new GeraMatrizThread(linha, coluna, a, b, r));
            t.start();
            thread[linha][coluna] = t;
        }
    }

    for (int linha = 0; linha < a.length; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < b[0].length; coluna++) {
            thread[linha][coluna].join();
            System.out.print("[" + r[linha][coluna] + "] ");
            System.out.println(thread[linha][coluna].getId());
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O currentThread() só funciona para a thread que estiver rodando no momento.

Cada Thread precisa rodar esta parte. 
Então, você pode colocar algo assim no construtor das threads para capturar o id e manter esse código para quando você precisar. Ou na função que cada thread usa para rodar pegar o ID e imprimir ele.

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
System.out.println("Thread ID:" + threadId);
```

Comment: Isso! Só que eu coloquei isso no metodo run e sempre imprime a mesma ID

Comment: Melhorei a resposta então. O currentThread só funciona para pegar o ID da thread que estiver rodando.

Comment: Então eu mantenho esse codigo no metodo run ?

Comment: Essa é uma opção... talvez executar uma vez em cada thread. Mas lá dentro funcionaria.

Comment: Ok,coloquei o trecho no código no método run,mas é normal não mudar o ID ? Já executei o codigo 5 vezes e o ID nao muda

Comment: É normal sim. Threads podem ter o mesmo código se forem de processos diferentes também.

Comment: Ah,então está certo. Vou manter ela no metodo run